# How to have a unique url for every user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

New code for routes.js and login.ejs:

```
`module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    // =====================================
    // HOME PAGE (with login links) ========
    // =====================================
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('./pages/index.ejs'); // load the index.ejs file
    });

    // =====================================
    // LOGIN ===============================
    // =====================================
    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('./pages/login.ejs', { message: req.flash('error') });
    });

    // process the login form
    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true
    }));

    // =====================================
    // SIGNUP ==============================
    // =====================================
    app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {

        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('./pages/signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
    });

    // process the signup form
    app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));

    // =====================================
    // PROFILE SECTION =========================
    // =====================================
    // we will want this protected so you have to be logged in to visit
    // we will use route middleware to verify this (the isLoggedIn function)
    app.get('/profile/:id', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        var id = req.params.id;

        res.send('./pages/profile.ejs' + req.params.id);
    });

    // =====================================
    // LOGOUT ==============================
    // =====================================
    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    // =====================================
    // UPLOAD ==============================
    // =====================================
    app.get('/upload', function (req, res){
        res.render('./pages/upload.ejs');
    });

    // =====================================
    // PASSWORD RESET ======================
    // =====================================
    app.get('/forgot', isLoggedIn, function (req, res){
        res.render('./pages/forgot.ejs');
    });

    app.post('/forgot', function(req, res, next) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        done(err, token);
      });
    },
    function(token, done) {
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');
          return res.redirect('/forgot');
        }

        user.resetPasswordToken = token;
        user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

        user.save(function(err) {
          done(err, token, user);
        });
      });
    },
    function(token, user, done) {
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'SendGrid',
        auth: {
          user: '!!! YOUR SENDGRID USERNAME !!!',
          pass: '!!! YOUR SENDGRID PASSWORD !!!'
        }
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'passwordreset@demo.com',
        subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
        text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
          'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
          'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
          'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
      };
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        req.flash('info', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + ' with further instructions.');
        done(err, 'done');
      });
    }
  ], function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.redirect('/forgot');
  });
});



};

// route middleware to make sure
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }


    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    else{
    res.redirect('/');
    }
}`
```

And the view (login.ejs):

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">


<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

    <h1><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span>Login</h1>

        <% if(message.length > 0){ %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
    <% } %>

    <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Login</button>
    </form>

    <hr>

    <p>Need an account? <a href="/signup">Signup</a></p>
    <p>Forgot your or password? <a href="/forgot">Forgot</a></p>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

I could also have it like = `http://localhost:8080/profile/emailAddress`.

The emailAddress is given when signing up for my website.
The emailAddress is stored in my database that I set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
// store userId on login into session or any global variable 
var userId = req.session.userId
   res.redirect('/profile/'+userId) 
}); // =>directs to http://localhost:8080/profile for every signup.
```

Create new route with addition param

```
app.get('/profile/:id', function (req, res) {
 var id = req.params.id
 res.render('./pages/profile.ejs', {user: id});  
})
```

Comment: what if I wanted the number to be the same?

Comment: You can use userID instead of UTC time.

Comment: save userId value into session or any global variable to use it.

Comment: You are concatenate the userId on redirect url , are you using session or any other class to know user authentication on controller.

Comment: I am using sessions to know user authentication on controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should use request parameters. With express you can do the following:

```
app.get('/profile/:id', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    //do with id whatever you want
    res.render('./pages/profile.ejs', {user: req.user}); 
});
```

In your `isLoggedIn` middleware you will have something like this:

```
function(req, res, next) {
    if (isLoggedIn) { //check if the user is logged in
        req.user = user; //fetch the user from the DB or wherever you have it
    }
}
```

In your view you will use the user's id to build the url:

```
<a href="/profile/<%=user.id%>"><%=user.name%></a>
```

Comment: Can you explain the last part to me a little simpler? Like which view do I use the code signup or profile or login?

Comment: You will use this code in your other views to access the user's profile page. You can redirect the user to profile page when he signs up or logs in using `res.redirect`: `res.redirect('/profile/' + user.id);`

Comment: Can you explain with an example of a view? Sorry im new to node and express.

Comment: There's an example in the answer of how it could be done in any view if you pass the user object to it

Comment: And what is "user" in this exactly? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You will pass the current user object into the view like this:`res.render('viewname', {user: currentUser})`. Read on rendering views in express

Comment: Which user object? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Of the user that is currently logged in. Without seeing your `isLoggedIn` middleware it's hard to tell exactly what you should pass there, but usually it would be `req.user` if you're using `passport` for authentication.

Comment: Can you post the code on how to do it altogether.Thanks again.

Comment: I've added the pseudo-code for your middleware with comments

Comment: When I add the href it gives an error saying user is not defined

Comment: Which part the views, routes.js, app.js?

Comment: the route and the view

Comment: which view login, signup, profile? and my route.js is very big; not enough to fit this comment box.

Comment: Update your question with the code. Post the view where you render the link to profile, or you're not rendering it anywhere? Why do you need to render it if you have only 3 views? In this case you will simply redirect the user to his profile and that's it.