# How to generate a unique URL directory for every user?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to build a blogging application using `Nodejs, MongoDB and VueJs`. The backend API with all the CRUD operations will be built using NodeJS with the domain e.g. `api.domain.com`.

One of the requirements is to generate a unique public URL directory for every user that signs up for this application `(for e.g.: domain.com/user/usernameA)`

Problem: As I am new to this, how can I build such a feature where I can generate a unique public URL directory as mentioned above that can still call the APIs at `api.domain.com`?

Hope my explanation above is clear. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/

Comment: Has been answered, try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880276/how-to-have-a-unique-url-for-every-user

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From a backend perspective, that URL would be like an `id` for a user. In order to achieve that, I suggest you store the user URL on the Database. Let's say it is on the `user` table:

```
{
    _id: <ObjectId>,
    username: "alex", 
    email: "alex@example.com",
    url: "alex"
}
```

You just need to store the unique URL because the default user URL, which is in your case `domain.com/user/` would be the same for all of the users.

Let's say that URL would redirect to a user profile page. So when you redirect on your client code (In your case, Vue.js). Just add the URL on the default user URL like this:

```
"domain.com/user/"+url_user
```

If you want the unique URL to be the username of the concerned user, just directly insert the username to the `url` column on your database. Or if you want to **generate** a random string like this:

```
domain.com/user/XwPp9xazJ0ku5CZnlmgAx2Dld8SHkAeT
```

In Node.js you can use this [node-randomstring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomstring) library or follow this method from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript) StackOverflow discussion.

And for your question

> Problem: As I am new to this, how can I build such a feature where I
> can generate a unique public URL directory as mentioned above that can
> still call the APIs at api.domain.com?

No matter where you put your application, it should always be able to access the public API. By default, a domain (`api.domain.com`) is public and everyone can access it **unless the developer (I assume it is you) restricts it.** So the full control is on you.